# how to execute select query in Code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

I just started using CodeIgniter and would like to execute the query below. But I don't know how to write this using CodeIgniter. This query successfully executes in phpMyAdmin.

```
 SELECT sales.sales_id
       , sales.sales_date
       , sold_item.item_id
       , sold_item.quantity
       , general_sales.cust_id
 FROM sales 
        JOIN general_sales ON sales.sales_id =general_sales.general_sales_id
        JOIN sold_item ON general_sales.general_sales_id= sold_item.sales_id
 WHERE sales_date= ?
```

Comment: Read the active record class documentation....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code where $date is date you are looking for

```
$query = $this->db
->select("sales.sales_id,sales.sales_date,sold_item.item_id,sold_item.quantity,general_sales.cust_id")
->from("sales")
->join("general_sales", "sales.sales_id =general_sales.general_sales_id")
->join("sold_items", "general_sales.general_sales_id= sold_item.sales_id")
->where("sales_date", $date)
->get();
```

and then you can work with results with for example `$query->result_array()`

Comment: when i print this query like this var_dump($query).. its giving me null

Comment: that means empty result. You probably have bad value in $date. There should be same string as in raw mysql query

Comment: yeah yeah thanks it works ... but how can i print this query in my view .. because when in simple i used this $foreach($data as $row) echo $row->id .. but i cant print anything from this method by using join query ...

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [sales_id] => 142 [sales_date] => 2013-01-22 [item_id] => 3 [quantity] => 11 [cust_id] => 1 ) ) ..i am getting this result by using print_r($data) .. but i can echo like for example cust_id or anything by using for each

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object ..it is giving me this type of error

Comment: [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) is described how to manipulate data from query result. for example `foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}` if you want work with objects or `foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}` if with array